# No more SideBarEnhancements in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, package-control

I'm trying to install SideBarEnhancements in Sublime Text 2 (version 2.0.2 Build 2221), but it doesn't show under Package Control -> Install Package -> SideBarEnhancements.
Checking on [GitHub](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements) I see that it is a ST3 package but I'm sure it was available in ST2.
How can I install it on ST2?
It is no more available?
Thanks.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The maintained version of `SideBarEnhancements` now only supports Sublime Text 3. A public beta version of ST3 is [available for download](http://sublimetext.com/3), and I highly recommend upgrading if possible, unless you absolutely depend on some old ST2-only plugins, and there is no chance that they'll be ported to ST3/Python 3.3. Many plugins now support both versions, and more (such as `SideBarEnhancements`, `SublimeLinter`, and others) are now only officially supported on ST3.

However, if you must stay with ST2 for whatever reason, I've posted the last version of `SideBarEnhancements` to support ST2 [on Github](https://github.com/MattDMo/SideBarEnhancements-ST2), and I promise to not delete the repo! Installation instructions are provided in the [readme](https://github.com/MattDMo/SideBarEnhancements-ST2#installation).

**UPDATE**

As of September 2016, SideBarEnhancements and other packages by the same author have been removed from Package Control - see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39724497/1426065) for an explanation, such as it is. Going forward, to use SideBarEnhancements in ST3 you'll need to add the [Github repo](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements/tree/st3) (note that it's not a normal repo URL, as the main branch is `st3`, not `master`) to Package Control using the **`Package Control: Add Repository`** option in the command palette. This will ensure that your local installation is updated.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm in ST2 (as a rule of thumb I don't upgrade the software I use unless there is a specific and unavoidable reason or really a big advantage).

Comment: It took me forever to figure out why the package wasn't in the Package Control list...finally. Thanks for the info!

Comment: It doesn't work for me on windows 7, don't see the SideBarEnhancements in ST2 even after following the given instructions.

Comment: Thanks guy, your package works good on elementaryOS and sublime text 2 version.

Comment: @physiocoder Normally it's better to upgrade unless there's a good reason *not* to. Otherwise you'll get stuck with a pile of outdated, unmaintained software.

Comment: @MattDMo I didn't realize the version 3 beta was usable yet. Giving that a try now!

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser Better by which parameter? Usually upgrading you get incompatibilities, incosistencies, new bugs, features that get in your way... so I'll stick with "unless there is a specific reason (security, incompatibility with OS) or a big advantage (really useful new features)" :-)

Comment: @physiocoder "Usually upgrading you get incompatibilities, incosistencies, new bugs" Only if you're using crappy software to begin with. Good developers (such as the Sublime team) know how to make sure their releases actually work. Besides, by staying current, you make sure that you don't get stuck with unsupported software.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser Upgrading to ST3 is not an option, as it keeps crashing every few hours. And this is on a pristine install under ubuntu. Can't really trust a version (ST3) which keeps crashing and the next fix (dev release) for **ST3** comes after a 6 month wait. Am still sticking to ST2 due to only this reason, otherwise there would be no issue in switching.

Comment: @KumarHarsh did you install from the `.deb` available from sublimetext.com or another method? Are you sure you're running the latest release? I run ST3 on all 3 supported platforms, and it's been solid as a rock - the only issues I've had are directly related to plugins. If you'd like to troubleshoot further, feel free to [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and we can look into it further.

Comment: @KumarHarsh I haven't had any crashing issues at all with ST3 on Mac OS, nor with ST2 on Ubuntu. I haven't tried ST3 on Ubuntu yet.

Comment: It's just ST3+Ubuntu (was on 13.04 as well as 14.04)

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser Well, I am giving it a shot, been trying it the whole day. Although ST3 hasn't crashed yet, it is still buggy: The Menu bar gets hidden as soon as I change any setting in sublime (switch a theme, change a color-scheme, etc). Then I have to restart sublime to get the menu-bar back. Weirdest bug in the app I've seen yet...

Comment: @KumarHarsh Oh, that's not good. Is http://superuser.com/questions/693028/how-do-i-get-my-menu-bar-back-in-sublime-text-3-linux helpful?

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser thanks for that. It worked. I am assuming this has to be a bug, right?

Comment: As the link in the answer is broken, you can also download the file from github - https://github.com/samuelbran/SideBarEnhancements

Comment: @hireSwish which link is broken - the Dropbox one? I just downloaded from it just now...

Comment: @MattDMo Sorry i just remembered that Dropbox is blocked at my work which is why it wasn't working for me. I'll leave the github link there anyway just in case someone needs it one day.

Comment: Neither Dropbox, nor GitHub link work anymore. Anyone to the rescue?

Comment: @honza_p I've posted a new link to Github. It will remain valid for as long as Github is around.

Comment: It doesn't work for me and I'm on Build 3126.. Won't show up in Package Control

No luck trying to trigger it or searching for it in Package Control either.

No results, and I thought I had it installed previously..

Do I need to reinstall Sublime Text?

Comment: @achoukah All of the packages by the author of SideBarEnhancements have been removed from Package Control - see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39724497/1426065) for an explanation. So, you'll need to add the Github repo to Package Control using the `Add Repository` command. I'll update the answer.