# How to save collapsed / folded code in Sublime Text after removal of bufferscroll plugin

Tags: sublimetext3, folding

Is there a way to save/sync collapsed code from session to session in Sublime Text 3, now that the [BufferScroll](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/BufferScroll) plugin has been removed?

Comment: you can still install the package manually from the GitHub repo

Comment: Cool! Didn't know that. It works perfectly :) You can write your solution as an answer and I'll accept it. Otherwise I'll write my own answer in a couple of days. And thank you :)

Comment: @KeithHall, `BufferScroll` doesn't save/remember nested fold states.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the background story (I can't find the link, the author might have deleted it, so I'm paraphrasing). Basically, the author of Package Control requested that, instead of using dates as version numbers (such as `2016.03.18.06.34.41` for the most recent version of BufferScroll), package authors should use [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) similar to how Github suggests. [titoBouzout](https://github.com/titoBouzout), who is not only the author of BufferScroll, but of many other *very* popular packages such as [SideBarEnhancements](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements), [Tag](https://github.com/titoBouzout/Tag), and [SideBarGit](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarGit), tried converting his style to something like `v2016.03.18`, but apparently Github thought the version number was too high. Or something. I wish I had the original explanation.

At any rate, he was unable to do that, and got all upset (to put it politely) when informed/told that he would *have* to move to a versioning scheme that nearly all other software on Package Control uses. Instead, he decided to take his ball and go home. He's keeping his own versioning scheme, and keeping his packages available on Github, but they won't be on Package Control any more.

Users will manually have to open the Command Palette, select *`Package Control: Add Repository`*, then enter the Github URL to the repo, such as https://github.com/titoBouzout/BufferScroll (make sure there's no `.git` on the end). They will need to do this for *each and every* titoBouzout package they want to use. The advantage of this method over directly `git clone`ing into the `Packages` directory is that updates are pushed automatically, just like with Package Control packages.

**EDIT** Fortunately, even though all issues have been deleted from SideBarEnhancements, I still had the [relevant issue](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:1RoFrFm6ph0J:https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements/issues/327+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) (Google cache of page before deletion) open on my work laptop. Here is the author's explanation:

> Yes, I had problems to add new packages to the repository because there's a "new"(has some time there) requirement to maintain a version number, and I don't want to maintain versions numbers, because to me a date is enough already. I attempted to automate the version number by adding something without any meaning, just a date, but that broke the complete repository because "large number". So because of this disagreement, I removed all my packages from there. Rules changed, so Im no longer interested to distribute my packages via that channel. However you may decide to add this package manually via the option "Add Repository", this may or may not work, Im not uptodate with the requirements of that to work, and as I say, Im not interested.

**UPDATE**

So, it appears the author has caved to pressure, or changed his mind, or something, but all [his packages](https://packagecontrol.io/browse/authors/titoBouzout) are now available again via Package Control, at least for now.

Comment: As of 2017/Aug/03, BufferScroll has been removed from PackageControl (see https://packagecontrol.io/packages/BufferScroll).

Answer (score 29):

You could use `Auto​Fold​Code` which is package just for that xD. It's available via package control.

Comment: Awesome tip! It might be worth mentioning that this is a new solution -- it appears that AutoFoldCode has only been in package control for a few months (as of July 2017). That's certainly not a complaint, it's just nice context to have.

Comment: I think, too, that this should be the new solution, as it works as expected, and it's in the standard source (Package Control).

Comment: @user6003859 no, he didn't remove the project. See here: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AutoFoldCode and here: https://github.com/RIDE-2DAY/AutoFoldCode